# SQL Server using STUFF, Function

Tags: sql-server

I've two tables `department` and `employees`. I have an assignment to show the employees that belong to a given department in one row using a table-valued function.

Example

```
[clothes] [mike, aaron, shannon, etc]
[games]   [charles, darwin, bob, etc]
```

As I'm new to SQL Server I've tried to use cursors with functions, but the cursors was so difficult to understand and use. I tried to use stuff with function and there were error. I hope that someone could help me out

```
ALTER FUNCTION cursorit2()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
      (SELECT c.dept_name,
              STUFF((SELECT ',' + s.emp_fname + s.emp_lname
                     FROM   Employee s
                     WHERE  c.dept_no = s.dept_no
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
       FROM   Department AS c
              INNER JOIN Employee AS s
                      ON s.dept_no = c.dept_no)
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @MilenPavlov - Probably `CREATE FUNCTION failed because a column name is not specified for column 2.
`

Comment: it's msg4514 CREATE FUNCTION failed because a column name is not specified for column 2.

Comment: As @MartinSmith suggested you need to specify name for the second column  .... ` FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as names ....`

Comment: just can't understand why people here are down voting the question? is there something wrong with it? didn't the down voters even bother to write the reason for down voting SO WE CAN LEARN from our mistakes?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER FUNCTION cursorit2()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
      (SELECT c.dept_name,
              STUFF((SELECT ',' + s.emp_fname + s.emp_lname
                     FROM   Employee s
                     WHERE  c.dept_no = s.dept_no
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as yourColumnName --add name here
       FROM   Department AS c
              INNER JOIN Employee AS s
                      ON s.dept_no = c.dept_no)
```

Comment: it worked, is it possible to show how we could implement cursors to get same results *just curiosity to learn*?

Comment: There are many resources/examples online (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/). Would strongly advice not to use cursors due to performance issues.